# cannot access file because it is being used in another process: problem downloading pip

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, pip

[image]

i've tried the whole python -m pip install -U --force pip and python -m pip install --upgrade pip

neither have fixed my problem, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking at active processes to see if there are any that may indeed be accessing those files?

Comment: @MichaelBonnet the only process that could possibly be accessing those files would be visual studio, which I'm using to run the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by having visual studio actively running. To be sure you can shut down visual studio and check processes in your task manager. If it is holding open processes, you can either kill the process, or to be 100% certain, did the pip upgrade after a reboot (although this shouldn't be needed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).